# WPF - why use routed commands when auto-wiring available?

Tags: wpf, binding, command

OK, so here's question that's been puzzling me. People seem to go to convoluted lengths to implement routed commands etc. so that commands invoked in a WPF UI can be implemented in the view model. Yes, I get that this makes it easy to write unit tests for a button click for instance against the view model rather than having to physically press a button to test a piece of functionality. But, surely when you double-click a control on a XAML form, Visual Studio, creates a stub for that click in the code behind of the page. Now in that code-behind if you call a method in the ViewModel that has the button click functionality you wish to implement surely that still gives you the ability to test that functionality from unit tests without having to go to all the bother of implementing classes and routed commands just so you can bind to them from the UI.
To explain this better,
Suppose you have a button in the XAML  defined like this:

```
<Button Content="Go!"  Height="20" Width="50" Click="Button_Click" />
```

When you double-click it, the following code behind is generated, and all you need to do is call the handling code in the viewmodel. In the code below, the method is called GoPressed in the ViewModel and "vm" is a reference to the ViewModel class

```
 private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            vm.GoPressed();
        }
```

Obviously, I'm missing something here since no-one seems to be doing what I'm suggesting but to me it just sounds a bit 'purist' to try and keep ALL code out of the code-behind when surely there's nothing wrong with just keeping the event handler in it and using the viewmodel to implement the functionality. Best of both worlds is it not?

Comment: Sure, you can do that. The problem is that most components don't get their view model in the constructor, so they have to use DataContext, which isn't generic, so you really end up doing `(DataContext as MyViewModel)?.GoPressed();` which is just smells hacky.

Comment: Hmm, OK though, I'd argue - despite its 'hacky smell' it is still a valid way to call the command and IMHO a lot easier to understand than routed commands. In fact the way you need to implement routed commands seems a lot more hacky than an out-of-the-box straight binding support of commands that Microsoft could surely have provided?

Comment: Commands are very straight forward (and, if you think outside the box, can be very useful in encapsulating behavior) and are baked into the pattern. They don't require casting objects in order to function. MS provided a whole truckload of tools, I wouldn't spend much time worrying about what extra tools they didn't ship. That's where we come in.

Comment: Could you possibly show me a bit of code that achieves the same as the above? Maybe I’ve been reading the wrong  posts on this but if they are very straightforward as you say, then I’d be keen to see how to implement the example i showed above. Please show the xaml and the viewmodel code so i can see how its all wired up.

Comment: I'm not understanding. "Routed commands" aren't convoluted, nor is binding them in the UI. You have a single implementation (whichever you like, I've got my own I prefer) and you use it everywhere. I'm not sure where the complexity you're complaining about is.